# External wireless dongle ASUS USB-N13 keeps dropping connection since 16.04 update

Tags: networking, 16.04, usb, asus

Ever since the 16.04 update, my ASUS USB-N13 keeps dropping connection entirely from time to time and requires to be manually removed then reconnected to the PC. I have no idea what the issue is. I tried reinstalling the non-default drivers since the update with no success.

Here is the output of wireless-info: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23133594/ the network I am trying to connect to is MEUNIER ROSS

Thanks!

Avery

Comment: Irrespective of other tweaks that you may need and/or a different driver, I strongly recommend you change your router settings: Always WP2-AES, not any WPA/WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP.

Answer (score 0):

There are a very few drivers that both claim the same device, The driver *8192cu* that you installed from dkms and the driver *rtl8xxxu* are two examples. They both claim your wireless device and, no doubt, conflict. Let's blacklist one and see if your wireless now performs as expected. Please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo -i
modprobe -r rtl8xxxu
echo "blacklist rtl8xxxu"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

It may take a reboot. Any improvement?

Comment: Thanks! I'll test it out for a day or two and update if it worked.

Comment: Unfortunately the problem still persists after using this solution.

Comment: May we see: `dkms status` ? With this information, I will edit my answer to propose a more comprehensive solution.

Comment: Sorry for the long wait, dkms status shows: '8192cu, 1.10, 3.19.0-58-generic, x86_64: installed
8192cu, 1.10, 4.4.0-34-generic, x86_64: installed
'

Comment: Please try  `echo "options 8192cu rtw_power_mgnt=0 rtw_enusbss=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/8192cu.conf` and reboot and see if it works better

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately no improvement :(

Comment: How did you install the 8192cu dkms?

Comment: I have no idea to be honest.

Comment: Try `sudo dkms remove 8192cu/1.10 --all` to remove it.  Then see http://askubuntu.com/a/821796/300665 to install a driver chili555 recommends

Comment: Issue still persists with rtlwifi-new driver.

Comment: Please run the wireless script again and post a link to the results