# WiFi connection is not working

Tags: drivers, wireless, 16.04

Ive just installed ubuntu and it won't let me connect to wifi. i can connect with a ethernet cable but im not leaving my laptop beside the internet box all day... So if someone could tell me how to fix this that would be great! Im using Ubuntu 16.04 If thats any help.

Input:

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
```

Output:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723AE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8723]
Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723AE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:0723]
Kernel driver in use: rtl8723ae
Kernel modules: rtl8723ae
```

`rfkill list`

```
0: Toshiba Bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

Laptop: Toshiba sattelite C855-1RM

Comment: Jonathan, You need to provide more information. For instance, can you see the SSID of any network? That is, click on the network icon and see if there are any available networks. If you can, it may be an authentication issue. If not, check first if your wireless card is enabled. Again, click on the status bar network icon and ensure the wireless is enabled. Otherwise, you may want to provide hardware and version information.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Juan A. Carretero, i cant see the ssid of any network... and how do i enable my network card? also i have a toshiba sattelite c855-1rm if you need any more info tell me and i will get it.

Comment: I did that. Can you find out whats wrong -Juan A. Carretero

Comment: Please also add output of `rfkill list`.

Comment: There must be a hardware switch to enable Wi-Fi.

Comment: do you know how to enable the hardware switch? -Pilot6

Answer (score 1):

Install this driver for RTL8723AE. Connect to the internet by wire and run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt update
sudo apt install rtlwifi-new-dkms
```

If UEFI is used in your laptop, you will also need to disable Secure Boot in BIOS to enable this driver.

Comment: that didn't work so here's the output for rfkill list